# AngularJS directive recompilation with custom compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have a so called "recursive" directive for implementing element hierarchy (like a tree) which contains instances of itself and such approach required me to implement a custom compiler function that I've found on Stack Overflow because Angular's compiler would otherwise just enter an infinite loop.

This is the factory with the compiler function:

```
SBApp.factory('RecursionHelper', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        compile: function(element, link){
            if(angular.isFunction(link)){
                link = { post: link };
            }
            var contents = element.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return {
                pre: (link && link.pre) ? link.pre : null,
                post: function(scope, element){
                    if(!compiledContents){
                        compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                    }
                    compiledContents(scope, function(clone){
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                    if(link && link.post){
                        link.post.apply(null, arguments);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

That code successfully breaks the infinite loop.

Now, the directive that uses this code is working flawlessly but I've come to a point where I need to force recompile the directive and it's children because of the data that changes in some of the parent scopes of the directive and I therefore need to watch the atribute value and update the directive and it's children accordingly to "propagate" the change through the so called tree structure that I have.

I've found this piece of code somewhere on the SO: `$compile(element.contents())(scope);`, but that doesn't cut it because I need to use my custom compilation function to break the infinite loop.

Here's the directive that I have:

```
SBApp.directive('collection', function(RecursionHelper, TemplateFactory, $compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            collection: '=',
            editable: '=?',
            adminEdit: '=?'
        },
        templateUrl:'templates/collection.html',
        compile: function(element){
            var l = function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.$watch('adminEdit', function() {
                    //I need help with this part
                });

            //rest of the   
            //scope functions
            //and directive code

            }; //end of link function
            return RecursionHelper.compile(element, l);
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is as following: I can't find the way to successfully call the `RecursionHelper.compile()` function inside the `scope.$watch` function and forcefully recompile the element if `adminEdit` attribute changes. I've tried every possible combination I could think of but nothing seems to work.

The only way that works is to add a third boolean variable and an ng-if before the directive and then switch the boolean variable twice to force remove and force add the element but that's not the clean solution I'm looking for.

How do I achieve forced compilation when using custom compiling function?

**Edit:** I've resolved the issue by using scope.$watch to update the data and found out that it was actually `track by $index` that was causing all the trouble by creating additional scopes I didn't need and it somehow messed with the hierarchical structure of the directives I was trying to create. Nonetheless, the question remains open as I am unable to find a way to dynamically recompile a directive with a custom compile function like the aforemenetioned one.

Comment: Do you really need the compile function? Does the directive content contains some HTML-Code, which has to be compiled? Otherwise, just use two-way-data-binding for your problem. A change will be updated automatically to all children-directives. Looks like you compile manually your stuff of your directive, no need for that.

Comment: `adminEdit` is a boolean variable and it is indeed updated in the children-directives but the problem occurs when I switch that boolean - the scope variables in children directive that depend on it aren't being re-calculated properly because they are unaware of the change as the code inside the link function executes only once when the directive is compiled. But, you gave me an idea. I "propagate" the `adminEdit` variable as an attribute, so I'll just try and add a `scope.$watch` function in terminal node directives and do the stuff to update the directive and see if that helps.

Comment: That's how you do it ;) just build a watcher to watch your desired attribute and do the stuff, what you do in the link function (put it in a function to avoid duplicated code)

Comment: Nope, that didn't help in this case. I obviously have some really deep and complex issue with ng-repeat that is rendering the collection tree and/or directives that requires a recompiling of the directive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the problem has been resolved. I was iterating through the collections with `ng-repeat` and using `track by $index`. As soon as I removed the `track by $index` the problem disappeared. That might have been creating the additional scope that gave me troubles. I'll report back if everything remains fine and update the question. The recompilation question is still in place, though.